# Derivation of the force exerted by an electromagnet on a ferromagnetic object

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I've recently come across an equation describing the lifting force exerted by an electromagnet on a ferromagnetic object, separated by some distance. The equation has been outlined below, where $F$ is the lifting force, $μ_0$ is the magnetic constant, $N$ is the number of turns, $I$ is the current, $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the core and $g$ is the gap between the object and the electromagnet.

$$
F = μ_0\frac{(NI)^2 A}{2g^2}
$$
I was wondering if anyone knows how to derive this, as I've searched books and online resources and have found nothing on where it comes from.

Comment: I doubt that this formula is correct. It says nothing about the properties of the material being lifted. Just being "ferromagnetic" is not enough to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

The atomic dipoles within a ferromagnetic material tend to line up with an applied magnetic field. Then each dipole is subject to a force which depends on the gradient of the field at its location.  Calculating a formula from that would be a challenge at best.  I'm guessing that the formula you have is an approximation developed by engineers based on measurements made with actual magnets.